# How do I save a viewer response to a server?

Tags: java, save

If I want to save a response to a query on a website I'm coding to a server, how would I do that?

Here's an example. If I had a site with a "Rate us" form, and a person answered with a "AWFUL SITE!" how would I be able to save & retrieve that information?

Comment: What are you starting with? Do you have an HTTP server? Any libraries/frameworks? This is _not_ the sort of problem you want to approach – especially as a beginner – with only vanilla Java SE.

Comment: I'm sorry, In that case, as a beginner, where SHOULD I start?

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. What's your baseline?

Comment: Strong suggestion: if Java happens to be your language of choice, then start with Eclipse and Tomcat: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

Comment: If something happens and I have to develop apps on Eclipse, then I will stop doing development on java, due to Eclipse. I hate it.

Comment: Thank you all. Does tomcat support html with java in it?

Comment: TOmcat is web server, I works all web resources, It waits any request from client(browser is example of client), And runs particular app to handle request, particular app will be your java web app.

Comment: @grz Etr: By "HTML with Java in it" , I understand you to mean "JSP", or "Java Servlet Pages".  Tomcat is a "servlet container".  This link might clarify the architecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want to do. I'll describe two of them.

1. You could append each rating to the end of a file on the web server. This would be done in a server-side scripting language usually, such as PHP or ASP.NET, and you would probably want to set the permissions on the file so that it's not readable to everyone.
2. You could set up a table in a database (MySQL or otherwise) and add a new row for each rating given. Again, this would be done in something like PHP or ASP.NET and you would want to make sure you take precautions against SQL injection attacks (not much of a problem if you use PHP Data Objects rather than the deprecated mysql_* functions).

I would personally go for the second option as it's easier to manage and change, and it's easier to set it up so that you can store IP, name, optional email and message in every row. And like I said, you can add a new field later down the line without running into the obvious problems.

Comment: I hasten to add that there are many other choices for "server side scripting languages" - including [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_rails) ... and Java servlets :)

Comment: I realize that, which is why I didn't suggest that PHP and ASP are the only ones.